# Computing parametrizations for a differentiable $2$-manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
\begin{equation}
C=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\:|\:0\leq x\leq 1,\:0\leq y\leq 1,\:z=x^{2}+y^{2} \}.
\end{equation}
Intuitively, this looks like a differentiable $2$-manifold with boundary, the boundary being the points at $z=1$.

I am looking to parametrize $C$ using the least possible charts. I think that I'll need two.

I have tried over and over to find such charts, but since I have to get the boundary, the problem got a little hard. I could come up with something like (for most of the manifold, missing a point)
\begin{equation}
f_{1}\colon[0,1)\times[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^{3}\qquad\qquad f_{1}(u,v)=(1-u,\:1-v,\:1-u^{2}-v^{2})
\end{equation}

But this one has the issue that $[0,1)\times[0,1)$ is not an open set of $\mathbb{H}^{2}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\:y\geq 0\}.$

Any tips? Thank you all.

**EDIT**

I feel like my failure could be in assuming that I could do that with only two charts. Since the boundary is kind of circular, it doesn't really look like $\mathbb{H}^{2}$.

Comment: I do not think your boundary is correct. There should be three parts and the one you already have is incorrect.

Comment: I am very doubtful that this is a manifold with boundary. It looks like a manifold with corners to me.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon Yes, as I wrote in the post, $f_{1}$ is not a chart since the set is not open. What should the boundary be?

Comment: @JohnMa What is a manifold with corners? Why you do not think it has boundary? It looks like neighborhoods of points at height $z=1$ locally resemble $\mathbb{H}^{2}$.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are referring to. At $z = 1$, some $(x, y) \in C$ such that $x^2 + y^2  =1$ are lying in the interior: for example $(1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: @JohnMa Well, the equation $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$ describes a paraboloid in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, right? If you restrict it to $z=1$ you get the points I mean. Locally, neighborhoods of these points that are in $C$ look like $\mathbb{H}^{2}$. I am not sure what you meant by interior. Topological interior? Sorry, I didn't understand your explanation with the point $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ , can you make it a little clearer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The set $C\cap \{ z=1\}$ in $C$ is not the boundary of $C$, as there are point in this set $(1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2)$ so that there is a small open set containing this point so that $U$ looks like an open set in $\mathbb R^2$. The boundary, if I have to guess, should be those point $(x, y, x^2 + y^2)$, where $(x, y) \in \partial [0,1]^2$.

Comment: @JohnMa The actual point should be $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2},1)$, right? because this is the point that is in $C$. So we would need a neighborhood of the point the intersected with $C$ looks like an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and that looks absurd. Possibly I misunderstood what you mean by using only two coordinates, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes it should be $(1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2, 1)$.

Answer (score -2):

One chart is enough. Take $I=[0,1]$ and $$f:I^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3:(u,v)\mapsto (u,v,u^2+v^2)$$.

Comment: This set $I^{2}$ is not open neither in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ nor in $\mathbb{H}^{2}$.

Comment: Can't you parameterize manifolds with boundary with sets with boundary?

Comment: I believe that the standard definitions ask for the domains of the charts to be open in $\mathbb{H}^{n}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $\mathbb{H}^{n}$ is given the subspace topology. The set $[0,1)$, for instance, is open in $\mathbb{H}^{1}$, because $[0,1)=(-1,1)$$\cap$$\mathbb{H}^{1}$. And you can tell intuitively that the left side of the set $[0,1)$ looks like the "end" of a "curve with boundary". So open sets of $\mathbb{H}^{n}$ ,even not always they look open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ . Boundary is a bad word because it has also a topological meaning which is not the same as the one I mean here.

Comment: OK so you could use 4 charts (not optimal) for the atlas. Each one with a "boundary" and cover from the outside to almost the opposite side?

Comment: Of course I would like to delete my answer given this information. But on my cellphone this is not doable.